# Automate login to webpage with embedded JavaScript without using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests-html

I have used Selenium with the Chrome driver successfully to login to a webpage on my development computer but I need to be able to do the same on a computer that doesn't have internet access. The webpage has embedded JavaScript that validates the login process by username first then fires JavaScript to load another page for the password.

I can't use Selenium on the host computer since I can't download the chrome driver and the IT department will push new Chrome versions which will render my application un-useable.

I've tried request-html and PyQt but can't seem to get the JavaScript to execute on the host computer.

I've tried Requests, Requests-html, PyQt4 and 5.  I've looked at a few others but they don't have much on the way to interface with JavaScript.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If the "host computer" doesn't have internet access, how could you request anything at all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The computer is only connected to the internal network and Chrome is used to connect to a virtual server.

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternative to using Selenium due to the lack of internet access since I cannot download a compatible driver when the Chrome version changes.